# Yup.when: "`NaN` (cast from the value `NaN`)"

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup

I'm trying to implement a quite basic validation for a form field/select. Validation schema:

```
vehicleProvider: Yup.object() // This is an object which is null by default
    .required('formvalidation.required.message')
    .nullable(), 
reserveVehicle: Yup.number().when('vehicleProvider', { // This is a number which is null by default
    is: provider => provider?.hasReserve,
    then: Yup.number()
        .required('formvalidation.required.message')
        .nullable(),
    otherwise: Yup.number().notRequired()
}),
```

What I want to do: Only require/validate `reserveVehicle` if `provider.hasReserve` is `true`. Otherwise, don't require the number.
I get this error:

> "reserveVehicle must be a `number` type, but the final value was: `NaN` (cast from the value `NaN`)."

This makes sense (kind of) because, well `null` is Not a number. But as I'm trying to tell it that it shouldn't be required, in my opinion it shouldn't try to evaluate it.

Did I miss any key concepts of `Yup`?

Comment: I think your `otherwise` might be the one causing you problems, try adding `.nullable()` to that one.

Comment: .typeError('The field should be a number') did the job for me.

Comment: `price: Yup.number().required().typeError('add your message here')`
it works for me when cast from value NaN is comming.

Answer (score 113):

You should use **typeError**

Here is an example from my code:

```
amount: Yup.number()
                    .typeError('Amount must be a number')
                    .required("Please provide plan cost.")
                    .min(0, "Too little")
                    .max(5000, 'Very costly!')
```

Comment: I now just set typeError(''), so no unwanted error is shown in my app

Comment: If the input comes from a text box, with `""` for the empty value, the `required` error never triggers. Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77355777/33080

Answer (score 21):

No need to use "typeError"

```
yup.number()
    .transform((value) => Number.isNaN(value) ? null : value )
    .nullable()
    .required('Required'),
```

Answer (score 11):

Use this piece of code .transform((value) => (isNaN(value) ? 0 : value))

```
age: yup
.number()
.transform((value) => (isNaN(value) || value === null || value === undefined) ? 0 : value)
.required()
.label("Age"),
```

Comment: This solution can still display a message at the same time compared to just returning an empty typeError(''). You can return null of there is no value instead of 0, make it nullable, and you can display a required error message.

Comment: isNan check for "" empty string just change the condition for null and undefined              .transform((value) => ((isNaN(value)  || value  === null || value === undifined)? 0 : value))

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
amount: yup.number().typeError("")
```

This will omit the validation message, but you should be **careful** when doing this.

Answer (score 0):

add typeError in `when`

```
vehicleProvider: Yup.object() // This is an object which is null by default
    .required('formvalidation.required.message')
    .nullable(), 
reserveVehicle: Yup.number().when('vehicleProvider', { // This is a number which is null by default
    is: provider => provider?.hasReserve,
    then: Yup.number()
        .typeError('Amount must be a number')
        .required('formvalidation.required.message')
        .nullable(),
    otherwise: Yup
        .number()
        .typeError('Amount must be a number')
        .notRequired()
}),
```

Answer (score -3):

Since you want the field to still validate when the value is `NaN` and it's not a required field, changing your `otherwise` to this should fix it:

`otherwise: Yup.number().notRequired().nullable()`

Adding the `.nullable()` at the end is the key.

Comment: The problem is with the typecasting, the solution here fix it https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/500#issuecomment-818582829