# Yup - input field as a postive integer number and required

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I have the following:

```
 const schema = yup.object().shape({
    closedBugs: yup
      .number()
      .typeError("Please enter a valid number")
      .positive("Please enter a positive number")
      .integer("Please enter an integer")
      .nullable(false)
      .required("This field is required"),
  });
```

It works fine except that in case the field is empty, I don't get the message `This field is required but instead, it says` Please enter a valid number`.
Is this by design or something is dodgy here?

Comment: This was the resolution to it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69461015/value-type-error-message-displaying-instead-of-required-error-message-on-empty-i?rq=2